# How shall I use ProtocolBuffer's FieldMasks?

Tags: protocol-buffers

We are only recently adopting ProtocolBuffers in out platform, and I've seen the introduction of the FieldMasks in v3, but we can't seem to figure out how to use them.

We have generated our proto classes with v3 compiler, here's an example on how we intend to use them:

```
FieldMask fieldMask = FieldMask.newBuilder().addPaths("field1").build();
```

Now how do I apply this FieldMask to my proto generated class in order to perform a field search on it?

I've figured out how to perform searches through FieldDescriptors, but I can't seem to find the way to relate the FieldMask with the object I want to search in.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're supposed to use [the `FieldMaskUtil` class](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/FieldMaskUtil.java), which contains functions like `merge()` that will copy just the masked fields from one message into another.

Comment: Brilliant!, I wasn't aware of the protobuf-java-util library thanks